# This site can’t be reached CentOs 7 Apache

Tags: centos, lamp

Good Day!

I would like to ask for some help from the community because I downloaded a vagrant version of CentOs 7 ([bento/centos-7](https://app.vagrantup.com/bento/boxes/centos-7)) and I was able to access SSH and SFTP using the following credentials:

**Host:** 127.0.0.1
**Username:** vagrant
**Password:** vagrant

Then I started installing LAMP Stack on this instance by following this [LAMP STACK] [2](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-install-lamp-stack-on-centos) installation guide. When I tried to access the web server of the Apache, I couldn`t access it using http://localhost as the URL; probably I`m missing some configuration of the CentOS Server.

I am hoping someone can help me since I am not really familiar with CentOs or the Linux it self.

See below screenshots:
[image]
[image]